# Error to update laravel 5.8 to laravel 7.0

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

```
PHP Fatal error: Declaration of App\Exceptions\Handler::report(Exception $exception) must be compatible with Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler::report(Throwable $e) in /Users/yasmin/projects/laravel/idtrue-laravel/app/Exceptions/Handler.php on line 8
```

I had this error when I tried to update **Laravel 5.8** to **Laravel 7.0**, It was solved updating **App\Exceptions\Handler.php** to:

```
<?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;
use Throwable;

class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
    /**
     * A list of the exception types that are not reported.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dontReport = [
        //
    ];

    /**
     * A list of the inputs that are never flashed for validation exceptions.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dontFlash = [
        'password',
        'password_confirmation',
    ];

    /**
     * Report or log an exception.
     *
     * @param  \Throwable  $exception
     * @return void
     *
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function report(Throwable $exception)
    {
        parent::report($exception);
    }

    /**
     * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Throwable  $exception
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     *
     * @throws \Throwable
     */
    public function render($request, Throwable $exception)
    {
        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }
}
```

Comment: There's an upgrade guide per version here: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/upgrade . Its a must to take a look at them. You will take much of the bugs out before even running the application.

Answer (score 1):

In order to upgrade laravel 5.8 to laravel 7, **it is recommended to first upgrade to laravel 6 following the laravel 6 upgrade guide, and check if it works without any problem then upgrade to laravel 7.**

To upgrade laravel 6 to 7 you should follow the upgrade guide and the solution you mentioned is already described in laravel upgrade guide here: laravel.com/docs/7.x/upgrade#symfony-5-related-upgrades.

*which says:*

> In App\Exceptions\Handler.php report, render, shouldReport, and
>   renderForConsole methods of your application's App\Exceptions\Handler
>   class should accept instances of the Throwable interface instead of
>   Exception instances.

```
use Throwable;

public function report(Throwable $exception);
public function shouldReport(Throwable $exception);
public function render($request, Throwable $exception);
public function renderForConsole($output, Throwable $exception);
```